# exam class - align problems horizontally using probsoln

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, exam, probsoln

I would like to create worksheets with problems filled by rows instead of columns. I am using `probsoln` to store and call the problems, but they always end up filling the worksheet vertically.  I tried putting them in a table, but I can't get that to work.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\PSNrandseed{2004}

\hideanswers

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{showanswers}}{\textbf{Solution Sheet}}{}
\loadrandomproblems{10}{AddingFractionsDatabase}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\foreachproblem{\thisproblem\\}%
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to pull one or two rows of problems from each file as needed. <strike>I would like to use exam class if possible.</strike>

**Test Database**

```
\newproblem{addfractions:1212} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = $} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$} 

\newproblem{addfractions:1213} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = $} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{6} + \frac{2}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$} 

\newproblem{addfractions:1223} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} = $} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{3}{6} + \frac{4}{6} = \frac{7}{6} = 1 \frac{1}{6}$} 

\newproblem{addfractions:1214} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = $} 
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{2}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1216}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{3}{6} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1256}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{6} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{6} = \frac{3}{6} + \frac{5}{6} = \frac{8}{6} = 1 \frac{2}{6} = 1 \frac{1}{3}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1217}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{7} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{7} = \frac{7}{14} + \frac{2}{14} = \frac{9}{14}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1227}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{7} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{7} = \frac{7}{14} + \frac{4}{14} = \frac{11}{14}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1237}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{7} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{7} = \frac{7}{14} + \frac{6}{14} = \frac{13}{14}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1247}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{7} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{7} = \frac{7}{14} + \frac{8}{14} = \frac{15}{14} = 1 \frac{1}{14}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1257}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{7} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{7} = \frac{7}{14} + \frac{10}{14} = \frac{17}{14} = 1 \frac{3}{14}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1267}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{7} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{6}{7} = \frac{7}{14} + \frac{12}{14} = \frac{19}{14} = 1 \frac{5}{14}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1218}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{4}{8} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{5}{8}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1238}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{8}= $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{8} = \frac{4}{8} + \frac{3}{8} = \frac{7}{8}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1258}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{8}= $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{8} = \frac{4}{8} + \frac{5}{8} = \frac{9}{8} = 1 \frac{1}{8}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1278}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{7}{8}= $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{7}{8} = \frac{4}{8} + \frac{7}{8} = \frac{11}{8} = 1 \frac{3}{8}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1219}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{9}= $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{9} = \frac{9}{18} + \frac{2}{18} = \frac{11}{18}$}
```

Comment: Can you add some example problems? It's difficult to test without a database to load.

Comment: \newproblem{addfractions:1212}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1213}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{6} + \frac{2}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1223}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{3}{6} + \frac{4}{6} = \frac{7}{6} = 1 \frac{1}{6}$}

\newproblem{addfractions:1214}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = $}
{$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{2}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$}

Comment: @NicoleMathisen Updated the question with the test database. In future do update in question rather than in comments to make question stand on it's own irrespective of comments, as comments don't have any backups(without UPS :) ).

Comment: Note that the exam class has its own mechanism for recording solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by keeping track of which column you are in as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\PSNrandseed{2004}

\hideanswers

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{showanswers}}{\textbf{Solution Sheet}}{}
\loadrandomproblems{10}{AddingFractionsDatabase}

\newcounter{colcount}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\foreachproblem{\thisproblem
 \global\stepcounter{colcount}%
 \ifnumless{\value{colcount}}{4}{&}{\global\setcounter{colcount}{0}\\}%
}%
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]